# Efficient storage for time-based actions

Tags: c++, containers, message-queue

Consider a system with a periodic timer, with a period T, and a set of events, where an individual event may fire at time k*T, k an integer. If the event has not been fired, it should be possible to cancel or reschedule the event to a later point in time.

- We can use an `std::map<timer_key, Event>` as storage, where timer_key is a pair of a `std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point` and a 64-bit sequence number. Then, it is possible to peek at the next event, to see if it has expired yet. If it has, it is fired and removed from the map. For cancellation or rescheduling, the event must be removed or extracted/reinserted. This either requires a secondary map, or storing the iterator somewhere.
- Another option is to use a heap. This would be the canonical solution if there was no need for cancellation or rescheduling. A priority queue would only allow to remove the first element. Thus, it is not directly applicable. However, if using `std::vector` together with `std::push_heap` `std::pop_heap` it should be possible to cancel the event by letting it be a no-op. The container would then be `std::vector<std::pair<timer_key, std::unique_ptr<Event>>>`. Here, a `std::unique_ptr` is used because the address of `Event` must be preserved if the vector is reallocated. Similarly to the solution based on `std::map` the pointer to the event is stored so it is accessible from the context that triggers removal.

I think both of these solutions seams quite complicated:

- Both of them require a reference to an element inside the container
- `std::map` is implies a lot of heap traffic, and worse memory locality
- A priority queue with invalidation will contain dead entries which will take up space until they have expired

Thus, the question is whether or not I have any other choice to solve this problem.

### Update:

I realized that if events always are scheduled with a constant delay, the `timer_key` values should always be a monotonic sequence. Am I right here?

Comment: For up to a few thousand `timer_key`s just use `std::vector` and linear search. The memory pre-fetcher and cache locality beat any other data structure.  If you wish to check measure it.  Also see [Modern C++: What You Need to Know](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJHgp1ugKGM&list=PLDm463QFRdzA4y0EJJOCb1tedxLZrAhFu&index=13) at 45:50

Comment: @RichardCritten ... and organized such that there is one array for keys, and another array for values.

Comment: Not necessarily as `std::unique_ptr<Event>` is very small and will have minimal effect.  So the overall size of `std::pair<timer_key, std::unique_ptr<Event>>` is still small.